# Codeigniter 3 migrate sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, migration

I use Codeigniter 3 framework for my application, and i use the migration library. I write an object which is create a 'user_type' table, and insert into three row.

Here is the code:

```
private $tableName = 'user_type';

public function up() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$this->tableName` (
                `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
                `name` CHAR(120) NOT NULL
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB;";

    $sql .= "INSERT INTO `$this->tableName` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
                (1, 'user'), (2, 'provider'), (3, 'admin');";

    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

If i want to use the migration, it drop an error message with this text:
A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `user_type` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'user'), (2,
>   'provider')' at line 4
>
> CREATE TABLE `user_type` ( `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , `name` CHAR(120) NOT NULL ) ENGINE =
>   InnoDB;INSERT INTO `user_type` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'user'), (2,
>   'provider'), (3, 'admin');
>
> Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/rentacar/application/migrations/20151211113200_usertype_table_data.php
>
> Line Number: 18

The interesting part of this, is if i echo the $sql variable, and run it in the phpmyadmin, it works well.

Comment: https://github.com/AimalAzmi/codeigniter-migrations

Try this, I've written a library for this which can be used very easily through the CLI. It can be used to create migrations files and run migrations backwards or forwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute multiple sql statements at once.
Split the statements and execute each statement like below.

```
private $tableName = 'user_type';

public function up() {
    // First
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$this->tableName` (
                `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
                `name` CHAR(120) NOT NULL
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
    $this->db->query($sql);

    // Second
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->tableName` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
                (1, 'user'), (2, 'provider'), (3, 'admin');";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dbfore` to create tables,

```
$this->load->dbforge();
$tableName = 'user_type';

$this->dbforge->add_field(array(
    'id' => array(
        'type' => 'TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL'
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'constraint' => '120',
    )
));

$this->dbforge->create_table($tableName);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
        (1, 'user'), (2, 'provider'), (3, 'admin');";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

See about [`dbforge`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html)

**EDIT**
In that case try breaking your query like this

```
$tableName = "user_type";
$sql = "";
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$tableName` (
        `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
        `name` CHAR(120) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
echo $this->db->query($sql);
$sql = "  INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
        (1, 'user'), (2, 'provider'), (3, 'admin')";

echo $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: I don't want to use dbforge, becouse pure sql is faster, and i have to write as lightweight program as i can

Comment: But we use `dbforge` to create tables in codeigniter.

Comment: If you are seriously arguing the performance difference of 5 decimal places of speed comparing pure sql vs dbforge why use a framework in the first place? I heard pure PHP was faster than CodeIgniter!